# Reading a byte array index from USB data buffer causes crash

Tags: android, multithreading, serial-port, buffer

My app reads data from an FTDI using USB Host mode. Every now and again I'll get an Android Runtime error when I'm reading the data from the buffer. The line where the error occurs is always something like `unitVIDLSB=buffer[8];` where `unitVIDLSB` is already initialized as a `byte` and `buffer` is a `byte []`. I'm just trying to get each individual byte as they each contain one set of information per byte. It completely works about 30% of the time. I've also tried changing the baud rate to something slower like 9600, but it didn't change the success rate.

The read procedure is handled in its own thread, and will pick up when there is a message to be received, and will indicate the appropriate length of the message (this has been working well). From there it checks the first four bytes and cascades through case statements to identify the received message and perform the handling from thereon. The message handler is run from the thread.

I've looked into `DataInputStreams` but it doesn't look very different than just using a byte array.

Any help or recommendations appreciated! Thanks!

Here's my read thread:

```
class ReadThread extends Thread {
final int USB_DATA_BUFFER = 8192;

public void run() {
    byte[] usbdata = new byte[USB_DATA_BUFFER];

    int readcount;
    int iWriteIndex = 0;
    int startIndex = 0;
    byte status;
    bReadThreadEnable = true;

    while (bReadThreadEnable) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        readcount = ftDev.getQueueStatus();

        if (readcount > 0) {

            if (readcount > USB_DATA_BUFFER) {
                readcount = USB_DATA_BUFFER;
            }

            ftDev.read(usbdata, readcount);

            shortBuffer = new byte[readcount];

            for (int j = 0; j < readcount; j++) {
                shortBuffer[j] = usbdata[j];
                if (usbdata[j] == (byte) 0xFE) { //if byte[0] isnt the starting byte, find it
                    startIndex = j;
                }
            }

            if (shortBuffer[startIndex] == (byte) 0xFE && shortBuffer[startIndex + 1] == (byte) 0x19) { //sync, message received


                MessageHandler(shortBuffer);

                shortBuffer = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Here's the MessageHandler:

```
    void MessageHandler(byte[] buffer) {
    bReadThreadEnable = false;
    switch (buffer[3]) { //get first message ID byte
        case (byte) 0x10:
            switch (buffer[2]) { //get second message ID byte
                case (byte) 0x02:
                    numberOfUnits = buffer[8];
                    inChannels = buffer[9];
                    outChannels = buffer[10];
                    dataChannelLinks = buffer[11]; //errors: 1
                    bPSIReceived = true;
                    break;
                case (byte) 0x03:
                    bPSIFailed = true;
                    break;
                case (byte) 0x05:
                    unitVIDLSB = buffer[8];
                    unitVIDMSB = buffer[9];
                    unitPIDLSB = buffer[10];//errors: 1
                    unitPIDMSB = buffer[11];
                    unitSNLSB = buffer[12];
                    unitSNMSB = buffer[13];
                    unitTypeLSB = buffer[14];
                    unitTypeMSB = buffer[15];
                    unitProfileLSB = buffer[17];
                    unitProfileMSB = buffer[18];
                    //Reduce to one variable, for commodity of printing and debugging 
                    unitVID = ((unitVIDMSB & 0xff) << 8) | (unitVIDLSB & 0xff);
                    unitPID = ((unitPIDMSB & 0xff) << 8) | (unitPIDLSB & 0xff);
                    unitSN = ((unitSNMSB & 0xff) << 8) | (unitSNLSB & 0xff);
                    unitType = ((unitTypeMSB & 0xff) << 8) | (unitTypeLSB & 0xff);
                    unitProfile = ((unitProfileMSB & 0xff) << 8) | (unitProfileLSB & 0xff);
                    unitNumberOfChannels = buffer[19];
                    bUIReceived = true;
                    break;
                case (byte) 0x06:
                    break;
                case (byte) 0x08:
                    unitVIDLSB = buffer[8];//errors: 2
                    unitVIDMSB = buffer[9];
                    unitPIDLSB = buffer[10];
                    unitPIDMSB = buffer[11];
                    unitSNLSB = buffer[12];//errors: 1
                    unitSNMSB = buffer[13];
                    channelIndex = buffer[14];
                    dataCTLSB = buffer[15];//errors: 1
                    dataCTMSB = buffer[16];
                    dataChannelPLSB = buffer[17];
                    dataChannelPMSB = buffer[18];
                    dataChannelTT = buffer[19];
                    unitVID = ((unitVIDMSB & 0xff) << 8) | (unitVIDLSB & 0xff);
                    unitPID = ((unitPIDMSB & 0xff) << 8) | (unitPIDLSB & 0xff);
                    unitSN = ((unitSNMSB & 0xff) << 8) | (unitSNLSB & 0xff);
                    dataChannelType = ((dataCTMSB & 0xff) << 8) | (dataCTLSB & 0xff);
                    dataChannelProfile = ((dataChannelPMSB & 0xff) << 8) | (dataChannelPLSB & 0xff);
                    bDCIReceived = true;
                    break;
                case (byte) 0x09:
                    break;
                case (byte) 0x0B:
                    OunitVIDLSB = buffer[8];
                    OunitVIDMSB = buffer[9];
                    OunitPIDLSB = buffer[10];
                    OunitPIDMSB = buffer[11];
                    OunitSNLSB = buffer[12]; //errors: 1
                    OunitSNMSB = buffer[13]; //errors: 1
                    OchannelIndex = buffer[14];
                    IunitVIDLSB = buffer[15];
                    IunitVIDMSB = buffer[16];
                    IunitPIDLSB = buffer[17];
                    IunitPIDMSB = buffer[18];
                    IunitSNLSB = buffer[19];
                    IunitSNMSB = buffer[20];
                    IchannelIndex = buffer[21];
                    linkStatus = buffer[22];
                    OunitVID = ((OunitVIDMSB & 0xff) << 8) | (OunitVIDLSB & 0xff);
                    OunitPID = ((OunitPIDMSB & 0xff) << 8) | (OunitPIDLSB & 0xff);
                    OunitSN = ((OunitSNMSB & 0xff) << 8) | (OunitSNLSB & 0xff);
                    IunitVID = ((IunitVIDMSB & 0xff) << 8) | (IunitVIDLSB & 0xff);
                    IunitPID = ((IunitPIDMSB & 0xff) << 8) | (IunitPIDLSB & 0xff);
                    IunitSN = ((IunitSNMSB & 0xff) << 8) | (IunitSNLSB & 0xff);
                    bDCLIReceived = true;
                    break;
                case (byte) 0x0C:
                    break;
            }
            break;
        case (byte) 0x11:
            switch (buffer[2]) { //get second message ID byte
                case (byte) 0x02:
                    byte[] temp = new byte[16];
                    bPDCReceived = true;
                    bPDCFailed = false;
                    break;
                case (byte) 0x03:
                    bPDCFailed = true;
                    break;
                case (byte) 0x05:
                    break;
                case (byte) 0x06:
                    break;
            }
            break;
        case (byte) 0x12:
            switch (buffer[2]) { //get second message ID byte
                case (byte) 0x02:
                    break;
                case (byte) 0x03:
                    break;
            }
            break;
        case (byte) 0x20:
            switch (buffer[2]) { //get second message ID byte
                case (byte) 0x02:
                    break;
                case (byte) 0x03:
                    break;
            }
            break;
        case (byte) 0x21:
            switch (buffer[2]) { //get second message ID byte
                case (byte) 0x02:
                    break;
                case (byte) 0x03:
                    break;
                case (byte) 0x05:
                    break;
                case (byte) 0x06:
                    break;
            }
            break;
    }
    bReadThreadEnable = true;
}
```

The catlog is this:

```
04-04 16:05:23.246 V/SmartFaceService - 3rd party pause(845): onReceive [android.intent.action.ACTIVITY_STATE/com.testapps.potato.e5e_app/resume]
04-04 16:05:23.256 I/E5E     (15741): onResume - reconnect
04-04 16:05:24.307 V/SmartFaceService - 3rd party pause(845): onReceive [android.intent.action.ACTIVITY_STATE/com.testapps.potato.e5e_app/recreate]
04-04 16:05:24.327 I/E5E     (15741): onResume - reconnect
04-04 16:05:24.377 I/WindowManager(845): Screen frozen for +252ms due to Window{42f8cf70 u0 com.testapps.potato.e5e_app/com.testapps.potato.e5e_app.Startup}
04-04 16:05:26.489 V/SmartFaceService - 3rd party pause(845): onReceive [android.intent.action.ACTIVITY_STATE/com.testapps.potato.e5e_app/pause]
04-04 16:05:28.321 I/E5E     (15741): onResume - reconnect
04-04 16:05:28.331 V/SmartFaceService - 3rd party pause(845): onReceive [android.intent.action.ACTIVITY_STATE/com.testapps.potato.e5e_app/resume]
04-04 16:05:28.631 V/WindowManager(845):   #2: Token{42f29618 ActivityRecord{42f33ae0 u0 com.testapps.potato.e5e_app/.Startup t124}}
04-04 16:05:28.631 V/WindowManager(845):   #6: Window{42f8cf70 u0 com.testapps.potato.e5e_app/com.testapps.potato.e5e_app.Startup}
04-04 16:05:29.562 V/SmartFaceService - 3rd party pause(845): onReceive [android.intent.action.ACTIVITY_STATE/com.testapps.potato.e5e_app/pause]
04-04 16:05:29.592 V/SmartFaceService - 3rd party pause(845): onReceive [android.intent.action.ACTIVITY_STATE/com.testapps.potato.e5e_app/create]
04-04 16:05:29.652 I/E5E     (15741): onResume - reconnect
04-04 16:05:43.636 I/E5E     (15741): onResume - reconnect
04-04 16:05:43.646 D/UsbSettingsManager(845): hasPermission: UsbDevice[mName=/dev/bus/usb/002/003,mVendorId=1027,mProductId=24577,mClass=0,mSubclass=0,mProtocol=0,mInterfaces=[Landroid.os.Parcelable;@4388e5e0]for {10422=true}
04-04 16:05:43.796 V/SmartFaceService - 3rd party pause(845): onReceive [android.intent.action.ACTIVITY_STATE/com.testapps.potato.e5e_app/resume]
04-04 16:05:44.597 I/NotificationService(845): cancelToast pkg=com.testapps.potato.e5e_app callback=android.app.ITransientNotification$Stub$Proxy@42f591a0
04-04 16:05:45.527 I/E5E     (15741): db created!
04-04 16:05:45.598 I/E5E     (15741): writing PDCP SYS INFO
04-04 16:05:45.598 I/E5E     (15741): sending:FE 19 01 10 00 00 00 00 
04-04 16:05:45.618 I/E5E     (15741): readcount:14
04-04 16:05:45.618 I/E5E     (15741): Start index is0
04-04 16:05:45.618 I/E5E     (15741): Message Received!
04-04 16:05:45.618 I/E5E     (15741): hex string is:FE 19 02 10 00 06 00 00 02 02 04 00 00 00 
04-04 16:05:45.618 I/E5E     (15741): No. of Devices: 2
04-04 16:05:45.618 I/E5E     (15741): No. of inchannels: 2
04-04 16:05:45.618 I/E5E     (15741): No. of outchannels: 4
04-04 16:05:45.618 I/E5E     (15741): No. of datachannels: 0
04-04 16:05:49.261 I/E5E     (15741): writing GET UNIT INFO
04-04 16:05:49.261 I/E5E     (15741): sending:FE 19 04 10 00 03 00 00 01 00 00 
04-04 16:05:49.281 I/E5E     (15741): readcount:22
04-04 16:05:49.281 I/E5E     (15741): Start index is0
04-04 16:05:49.281 I/E5E     (15741): Message Received!
04-04 16:05:49.291 I/E5E     (15741): hex string is:FE 19 05 10 00 0E 00 00 63 00 0E 00 09 00 00 01 00 01 00 03 00 00 
04-04 16:05:49.291 I/E5E     (15741): Get Unit Info Received!
04-04 16:05:51.423 I/E5E     (15741): writing GET PARAM INFO(1)
04-04 16:05:51.423 I/E5E     (15741): sending:FE 19 01 11 00 0A 00 00 63 00 0E 00 09 00 00 07 00 00 
04-04 16:05:51.733 I/E5E     (15741): waiting for PARAM INFO (1)
04-04 16:05:51.733 I/E5E     (15741): Got Param!
04-04 16:05:51.764 I/E5E     (15741): Number of Channels (for loop) 3
04-04 16:05:51.774 I/E5E     (15741): Channel index is:1
04-04 16:05:52.314 I/E5E     (15741): readcount:11
04-04 16:05:52.314 I/E5E     (15741): Start index is0
04-04 16:05:52.314 I/E5E     (15741): Message Received!
04-04 16:05:52.324 I/E5E     (15741): hex string is:FE 19 03 11 00 03 00 00 00 00 00 
04-04 16:05:52.324 E/E5E     (15741): Get Parameter Data Failed!
04-04 16:05:53.765 I/E5E     (15741): Writing DATA CHANNEL INFO
04-04 16:05:53.765 I/E5E     (15741): sending:FE 19 07 10 00 09 00 00 63 00 0E 00 09 00 01 00 00 
04-04 16:05:53.785 I/E5E     (15741): readcount:1
04-04 16:05:53.785 I/E5E     (15741): Start index is0
04-04 16:05:53.785 E/AndroidRuntime(15741): Process: com.testapps.potato.e5e_app, PID: 15741
04-04 16:05:53.785 E/AndroidRuntime(15741):     at com.testapps.potato.e5e_app.Startup$ReadThread.run(Startup.java:302)
04-04 16:05:53.796 W/ActivityManager(845):   Force finishing activity com.testapps.potato.e5e_app/.Startup
04-04 16:05:53.876 D/CrashAnrDetector(845): processName: com.testapps.potato.e5e_app
04-04 16:05:53.876 D/CrashAnrDetector(845): broadcastEvent : com.testapps.potato.e5e_app data_app_crash
04-04 16:05:53.876 V/SmartFaceService - 3rd party pause(845): onReceive [android.intent.action.ACTIVITY_STATE/com.testapps.potato.e5e_app/pause]
04-04 16:05:54.076 I/E5E     (15741): waiting for DATA CHANNEL INFO
04-04 16:05:54.226 I/E5E     (15741): waiting for DATA CHANNEL INFO
04-04 16:05:54.376 I/E5E     (15741): waiting for DATA CHANNEL INFO
04-04 16:05:54.526 I/E5E     (15741): waiting for DATA CHANNEL INFO
04-04 16:05:54.676 I/E5E     (15741): waiting for DATA CHANNEL INFO
04-04 16:05:54.827 I/E5E     (15741): waiting for DATA CHANNEL INFO
04-04 16:05:54.977 I/E5E     (15741): waiting for DATA CHANNEL INFO
04-04 16:05:55.127 I/E5E     (15741): waiting for DATA CHANNEL INFO
04-04 16:05:55.277 I/E5E     (15741): waiting for DATA CHANNEL INFO
04-04 16:05:55.427 I/E5E     (15741): waiting for DATA CHANNEL INFO
04-04 16:05:55.577 I/E5E     (15741): waiting for DATA CHANNEL INFO
04-04 16:05:55.637 I/ActivityManager(845): Process com.testapps.potato.e5e_app (pid 15741) (adj 1) has died.
04-04 16:05:55.637 I/WindowState(845): WIN DEATH: Window{439179f0 u0 com.testapps.potato.e5e_app/com.testapps.potato.e5e_app.Startup}
04-04 16:06:40.011 D/Launcher.Workspace(1508): changeState NORMAL -> EDIT, animated: true, delay: 0, item: Item(id=290 folderId=-1 screen=5 cell=11 title=E5E_app componentName=ComponentInfo{com.testapps.potato.e5e_app/com.testapps.potato.e5e_app.Startup} unavailable=false)
04-04 16:06:41.392 W/PackageManager(845): Couldn't delete native library directory /data/app-lib/com.testapps.potato.e5e_app
04-04 16:06:41.642 D/PackageManager(845): Sending to user 0: act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED dat=package:com.testapps.potato.e5e_app flg=0x4000000 Bundle[{android.intent.extra.REMOVED_FOR_ALL_USERS=true, android.intent.extra.UID=10422, android.intent.extra.DATA_REMOVED=true, android.intent.extra.user_handle=0}]
04-04 16:06:41.672 D/PackageManager(845): Sending to user 0: act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_FULLY_REMOVED dat=package:com.testapps.potato.e5e_app flg=0x4000000 Bundle[{android.intent.extra.REMOVED_FOR_ALL_USERS=true, android.intent.extra.UID=10422, android.intent.extra.DATA_REMOVED=true, android.intent.extra.user_handle=0}]
04-04 16:06:41.692 D/ContainerEventsRelayManager(1475): <<< Intent data is   >>> : package:com.testapps.potato.e5e_app
04-04 16:06:41.712 I/elm     (3585): MainReceiver.onReceive() : Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED dat=package:com.testapps.potato.e5e_app flg=0x4000010 cmp=com.sec.esdk.elm/.receiver.MainReceiver (has extras) }
04-04 16:06:41.792 D/ContainerEventsRelayManager(1475): <<< Intent data is   >>> : package:com.testapps.potato.e5e_app
04-04 16:06:41.832 I/elm     (3585): MainReceiver.onReceive() END - - - - - : Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED dat=package:com.testapps.potato.e5e_app flg=0x4000010 cmp=com.sec.esdk.elm/.receiver.MainReceiver (has extras) }
04-04 16:06:42.033 D/BackupManagerService(845): Received broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED dat=package:com.testapps.potato.e5e_app flg=0x4000010 (has extras) }
04-04 16:06:42.453 I/CrashAnrDetector(845): onPackageRemoved : com.testapps.potato.e5e_app
04-04 16:06:42.913 D/CapabilityManagerService New(17703): The package(com.testapps.potato.e5e_app) removed
04-04 16:06:43.324 D/PackageBroadcastService(1998): Received broadcast action=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED and uri=com.testapps.potato.e5e_app
04-04 16:06:43.324 D/AccountUtils(1998): Clearing selected account for com.testapps.potato.e5e_app
04-04 16:06:43.354 I/LocationSettingsChecker(1998): Removing dialog suppression flag for package com.testapps.potato.e5e_app
04-04 16:06:43.614 I/ConfigFetchService(1998): onStartCommand Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED dat=package:com.testapps.potato.e5e_app cmp=com.google.android.gms/.config.ConfigFetchService (has extras) }
04-04 16:06:43.654 I/Icing   (1998): doRemovePackageData com.testapps.potato.e5e_app
04-04 16:06:43.864 I/UpdateIcingCorporaServi(2769): Updating corpora: APPS=com.testapps.potato.e5e_app, CONTACTS=MAYBE
04-04 16:06:48.619 D/PackageManager(845):           PackageURI{file:///data/local/tmp/com.testapps.potato.e5e_app}
04-04 16:06:50.191 D/PackageManager(845): Sending to user 0: act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED dat=package:com.testapps.potato.e5e_app flg=0x4000000 Bundle[{android.intent.extra.UID=10423, android.intent.extra.user_handle=0}]
04-04 16:06:50.221 D/ContainerEventsRelayManager(1475): <<< Intent data is   >>> : package:com.testapps.potato.e5e_app
04-04 16:06:50.541 D/BackupManagerService(845): Received broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED dat=package:com.testapps.potato.e5e_app flg=0x4000010 (has extras) }
04-04 16:06:50.571 D/ECS_EnterpriseContainerService(845): <<< Intent data is   >>> : package:com.testapps.potato.e5e_app
04-04 16:06:51.272 D/FileShare-Server(18117): ServerBroadcastReceiver.onReceive - action android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED // package:com.testapps.potato.e5e_app
04-04 16:06:51.452 I/CrashAnrDetector(845): onPackageAdded : com.testapps.potato.e5e_app
04-04 16:06:51.452 D/PackageBroadcastService(1998): Received broadcast action=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED and uri=com.testapps.potato.e5e_app
04-04 16:06:51.492 V/ApplicationPolicy(845): isApplicationStateBlocked userId 0 pkgname com.testapps.potato.e5e_app
04-04 16:06:51.532 I/ConfigFetchService(1998): onStartCommand Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED dat=package:com.testapps.potato.e5e_app cmp=com.google.android.gms/.config.ConfigFetchService (has extras) }
04-04 16:06:51.642 V/SmartFaceService - 3rd party pause(845): onReceive [android.intent.action.ACTIVITY_STATE/com.testapps.potato.e5e_app/create]
04-04 16:06:51.722 I/E5E     (18172): onResume - reconnect
04-04 16:06:51.982 I/UpdateIcingCorporaServi(2769): Updating corpora: APPS=com.testapps.potato.e5e_app, CONTACTS=MAYBE
04-04 16:06:59.389 V/SmartFaceService - 3rd party pause(845): onReceive [android.intent.action.ACTIVITY_STATE/com.testapps.potato.e5e_app/pause]
04-04 16:07:01.772 I/E5E     (18172): onResume - reconnect
04-04 16:07:01.832 V/SmartFaceService - 3rd party pause(845): onReceive [android.intent.action.ACTIVITY_STATE/com.testapps.potato.e5e_app/resume]
04-04 16:07:02.262 I/NotificationService(845): cancelToast pkg=com.testapps.potato.e5e_app callback=android.app.ITransientNotification$Stub$Proxy@44e73bb0
04-04 16:07:03.213 I/E5E     (18172): db created!
04-04 16:07:03.273 I/E5E     (18172): writing PDCP SYS INFO
04-04 16:07:03.273 I/E5E     (18172): sending:FE 19 01 10 00 00 00 00 
04-04 16:07:03.293 I/E5E     (18172): readcount:14
04-04 16:07:03.293 I/E5E     (18172): Start index is0
04-04 16:07:03.293 I/E5E     (18172): Message Received!
04-04 16:07:03.293 I/E5E     (18172): hex string is:FE 19 02 10 00 06 00 00 02 02 04 00 00 00 
04-04 16:07:03.293 I/E5E     (18172): No. of Devices: 2
04-04 16:07:03.293 I/E5E     (18172): No. of inchannels: 2
04-04 16:07:03.293 I/E5E     (18172): No. of outchannels: 4
04-04 16:07:03.293 I/E5E     (18172): No. of datachannels: 0
04-04 16:07:06.927 I/E5E     (18172): writing GET UNIT INFO
04-04 16:07:06.927 I/E5E     (18172): sending:FE 19 04 10 00 03 00 00 01 00 00 
04-04 16:07:06.947 I/E5E     (18172): readcount:22
04-04 16:07:06.947 I/E5E     (18172): Start index is0
04-04 16:07:06.947 I/E5E     (18172): Message Received!
04-04 16:07:06.947 I/E5E     (18172): hex string is:FE 19 05 10 00 0E 00 00 63 00 0E 00 09 00 00 01 00 01 00 03 00 00 
04-04 16:07:06.947 I/E5E     (18172): Get Unit Info Received!
04-04 16:07:09.079 I/E5E     (18172): writing GET PARAM INFO(1)
04-04 16:07:09.089 I/E5E     (18172): sending:FE 19 01 11 00 0A 00 00 63 00 0E 00 09 00 00 07 00 00 
04-04 16:07:09.389 I/E5E     (18172): waiting for PARAM INFO (1)
04-04 16:07:09.389 I/E5E     (18172): Got Param!
04-04 16:07:09.439 I/E5E     (18172): Number of Channels (for loop) 3
04-04 16:07:09.439 I/E5E     (18172): Channel index is:1
04-04 16:07:09.960 I/E5E     (18172): readcount:11
04-04 16:07:09.960 I/E5E     (18172): Start index is0
04-04 16:07:09.960 I/E5E     (18172): Message Received!
04-04 16:07:09.970 I/E5E     (18172): hex string is:FE 19 03 11 00 03 00 00 00 00 00 
04-04 16:07:09.970 E/E5E     (18172): Get Parameter Data Failed!
04-04 16:07:11.441 I/E5E     (18172): Writing DATA CHANNEL INFO
04-04 16:07:11.441 I/E5E     (18172): sending:FE 19 07 10 00 09 00 00 63 00 0E 00 09 00 01 00 00 
04-04 16:07:11.471 I/E5E     (18172): readcount:22
04-04 16:07:11.471 I/E5E     (18172): Start index is0
04-04 16:07:11.471 I/E5E     (18172): Message Received!
04-04 16:07:11.471 I/E5E     (18172): hex string is:FE 19 08 10 00 0E 00 00 63 00 0E 00 09 00 01 01 00 01 00 01 00 00 
04-04 16:07:11.471 I/E5E     (18172): Get Data Channel Info Received!
04-04 16:07:13.603 I/E5E     (18172): Adding Params!
04-04 16:07:13.683 I/E5E     (18172): At channel switch!
04-04 16:07:15.685 I/E5E     (18172): writing GET DATA CHAN LINK INFO
04-04 16:07:15.685 I/E5E     (18172): sending:FE 19 0A 10 00 09 00 00 63 00 0E 00 09 00 01 00 00 
04-04 16:07:15.715 I/E5E     (18172): readcount:25
04-04 16:07:15.715 I/E5E     (18172): Start index is0
04-04 16:07:15.715 I/E5E     (18172): Message Received!
04-04 16:07:15.715 I/E5E     (18172): hex string is:FE 19 0B 10 00 11 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 63 00 0E 00 09 00 01 00 00 00 
04-04 16:07:15.715 I/E5E     (18172): Get Data Channel Link Info Received!
04-04 16:07:17.837 I/E5E     (18172): Adding more Parameters!
04-04 16:07:18.048 I/E5E     (18172): Done adding Parameters!
04-04 16:07:18.048 I/E5E     (18172): Channel index is:2
04-04 16:07:20.050 I/E5E     (18172): Writing DATA CHANNEL INFO
04-04 16:07:20.050 I/E5E     (18172): sending:FE 19 07 10 00 09 00 00 63 00 0E 00 09 00 02 00 00 
04-04 16:07:20.070 I/E5E     (18172): readcount:12
04-04 16:07:20.070 I/E5E     (18172): Start index is0
04-04 16:07:20.070 I/E5E     (18172): Message Received!
04-04 16:07:20.070 I/E5E     (18172): hex string is:FE 19 08 10 00 0E 00 00 63 00 0E 00 
04-04 16:07:20.070 I/E5E     (18172): Get Data Channel Info Received!
04-04 16:07:20.070 E/AndroidRuntime(18172): Process: com.testapps.potato.e5e_app, PID: 18172
04-04 16:07:20.070 E/AndroidRuntime(18172):     at com.testapps.potato.e5e_app.Startup.MessageHandler(Startup.java:379)
04-04 16:07:20.070 E/AndroidRuntime(18172):     at com.testapps.potato.e5e_app.Startup$ReadThread.run(Startup.java:310)
04-04 16:07:20.080 W/ActivityManager(845):   Force finishing activity com.testapps.potato.e5e_app/.Startup
04-04 16:07:20.170 D/CrashAnrDetector(845): processName: com.testapps.potato.e5e_app
04-04 16:07:20.170 D/CrashAnrDetector(845): broadcastEvent : com.testapps.potato.e5e_app data_app_crash
04-04 16:07:20.170 V/SmartFaceService - 3rd party pause(845): onReceive [android.intent.action.ACTIVITY_STATE/com.testapps.potato.e5e_app/pause]
04-04 16:07:20.360 I/E5E     (18172): waiting for DATA CHANNEL INFO
04-04 16:07:20.530 I/E5E     (18172): waiting for DATA CHANNEL INFO
04-04 16:07:20.680 I/E5E     (18172): waiting for DATA CHANNEL INFO
04-04 16:07:20.830 I/E5E     (18172): waiting for DATA CHANNEL INFO
04-04 16:07:20.981 I/E5E     (18172): waiting for DATA CHANNEL INFO
04-04 16:07:21.131 I/E5E     (18172): waiting for DATA CHANNEL INFO
04-04 16:07:21.281 I/E5E     (18172): waiting for DATA CHANNEL INFO
04-04 16:07:21.431 I/E5E     (18172): waiting for DATA CHANNEL INFO
04-04 16:07:21.581 I/E5E     (18172): waiting for DATA CHANNEL INFO
04-04 16:07:21.611 I/WindowState(845): WIN DEATH: Window{42f35680 u0 com.testapps.potato.e5e_app/com.testapps.potato.e5e_app.Startup}
04-04 16:07:21.621 I/ActivityManager(845): Process com.testapps.potato.e5e_app (pid 18172) (adj 11) has died.
```

Comment: `byte[] usbdata = new byte[USB_DATA_BUFFER];` Better create a new buffer everytime. So place that statement in the while loop. `shortBuffer = new byte[readcount];`. Make that a local buffer for the loop too: `byte [] shortBuffer = new byte[readcount];`.  Give it a try.

Comment: Thanks for the reply; however I'm still getting the same error with these changes.

Comment: But what is exactly the error? Please post the logcat.

Comment: You declared all kind of variables just before  the while loop.  Declare them in the while loop if you only use them in the loop. Isnt there a return value to be checked for ftDev.read()?

Comment: I'm using the USB port on the phone, so I have to use the catlog app. There's lots of debugging Logs, but this is what I see when this happens (updated the post).

Comment: It fails twice in this Log, the system querying starts at the "db created!" and sends data linearly and receives it through the read thread. The failures are very intermittent. I appreciated your help, any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: I may have found the error, if anybody ever runs into a similar situation. You need to make sure the message handling procedure only runs if the entire message has been captured in your buffer. I only just realized that the `readcount` variable is shorter than expected, meaning when the handler tries to read that part of the buffer and it is non existant, it will return a runtime error since it's trying to read from a non-existing index location. In my catlog there is `04-04 16:05:53.785 I/E5E     (15741): readcount:1`, a clear indicator that if it reads anything above 1 it will fail.

Comment: Confirming that this has solved my issues. I used this knowledge to figure out when to resend the query so that the return message will eventually be the right size and not missing parts of it. Thanks for your help @greenapps!